# он/Она and the -OM termination?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

If I want to say that someone has a lot of money and be specific about it (See below). Why is the -om terminatation added on the F form and what is the rule for that?

он миллионер. Она миллионером.

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect.  -ом ending is not added in the female form.  In both cases you would use nominative case. You would also use a dash (тире) before the noun in such construct:

> Он - миллионер.
>   Она - миллионер.

You can also use был/была verb in place of dash - and in this case you would add the -ом ending, as the noun is then used in instrumental case:

> Он был миллионером.
>   Она была миллионером.

Comment: Interesting to note, that there is a word "миллионерша" (you can probably encounter it in some literature), which means *the **wife** of a millionaire*.

Comment: как и генеральша - жена генерала; губернаторша - жена губернатора; ...

Comment: При этом "докторша" обычно используется для обозначения женщины врача, хоть это и не совсем правильно.